# How to use VueDraggable nested to clone element into layout

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, sortablejs, vuedraggable

i'm on nuxt 2.13 , vuetify 2, vuedraggable 2.24 .
i wanna drag from a list of events and drop it on my layout structure. but here are the issues:

1- my layouts are different like the picture bellow. first i choose the layout and then drop my events inside it.

2- when i drag my element to layout, i wanna detect where dropping it to highlight the border.

3- after drop not gonna show the element inside layout (nested) but instead send a request to backend and put the respond image and title inside it.

which `methods` , `props` and `@event` should i use for each part. for example in #2 how can i find out where i'm dropping to highlight the border of it?

My Layouts that i choose from for example:

[image] Or [image]

My actual drag & drop:

[image]

**Note:**
as i mentioned before, i'm not looking for someone to code for me. i just wanna know that is it possible with VueDraggable and what are the helper `events` and `methods` . thanks